# Nearby Connection suddenly stopped getting service when advertising/discovering around September 11, 2023. Was there a new update to the google api?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, google-nearby-connections

Prior to the date listed in the title, my app was able to advertise and discover other devices without a problem. However, I now have this error popping up when attempting to advertise/discover:

```
Getting service failed
```

> java.lang.IllegalStateException
> at agjh.l(:com.google.android.gms@233414044@23.34.14
> (190400-560151436):6)
> at
> com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.service.NearbyConnectionsChimeraService.a(:com.google.android.gms@233414044@23.34.14
> (190400-560151436):151)
> at bbks.a(:com.google.android.gms@233414044@23.34.14
> (190400-560151436):3)
> at bblq.a(:com.google.android.gms@233414044@23.34.14
> (190400-560151436):10)
> at bblt.gT(:com.google.android.gms@233414044@23.34.14
> (190400-560151436):840)
> at agie.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@233414044@23.34.14
> (190400-560151436):70)
> at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:1100)
> at atdw.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@233414044@23.34.14
> (190400-560151436):147)
> at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:1100)
> at aznn.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@233414044@23.34.14
> (190400-560151436):10)
> at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1215)
> at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1179)

> ```
> I Then also noticed this error when attempting to discover and after the Getting service failed error:
> ```
>
> Unable to start advertising. Report: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: API: Nearby.CONNECTIONS_API is not available on this device. Connection failed with: ConnectionResult{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null, message=null}

I tried reverting my save in github to a point where it was working with Nearby Connections, but my app still has the same problem. I also tried my app on other devices and it still doesn't work.

I looked into the issue with the error saying that Nearby.CONNECTIONS_API is not available on this device, but only found solutions if my device happened to not have Google Play, which my device does have. I am currently trying to run it on a Samsung Galaxy Note10+ 5G. I'm connected to the my Wifi, bluetooth is turned on, and location is turned on and it still doesn't fix anything.
I also tried restarting my device, turning airplane mode on and off, updating Android Studios and looked for any updates for my dependencies but have a hard time finding it and as far as I can see, my dependencies are up to date but I may be wrong. My current dependencies that include Google play services are as followed:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:18.7.0'
```

Comment: I confirm that Nearby Connections API is currently broken and does not work at all, due to a bug under-the-hood in the GPlay services in the very recent patches and therefore is **not fixable**. The only solution to get them working is to wait for a fix from Google devs.

The library was working fine up until two weeks ago, which checks out so you have nothing wrong with your code or anything else. I've tested it on an Android 10, 11, 12, 13 and 14 with different Nearby Connections library versions and Play services versions. `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable` turns `SUCCESS`, so, library issue

Comment: The issue has been brought to Google devs attention, and can be tracked here: https://github.com/google/nearby/issues/2124#issuecomment-1722458312